# Finding network addresses

Tags: ip-address, subnet

Consider a router that interconnects three subnets: Subnet1, Subnet2, and Subnet3.
Suppose all of the interfaces in each of these three subnets are required to have the prefix
223.1.17/24. Also suppose that Subnet #1 is to support at least 60 interfaces 
Subnet #2 is to support at least 90 interfaces
Subnet #3 is to support at least 12 interfaces.  Provide
three network addresses (of the form a.b.c.d/x) that satisfy these constraints.

What I thought is 
Subnet 1: 223.1.17.0/26
Subnet 2: 223.1.17.64/25
Subnet 3 : 223.1.17.192/28

Is this correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. You have the size calculations done correctly but subnet 1 and 2 will overlap. A /25 network must start at either 0 or 128.

The requirements for each network is:
60 rounded up to the nearest power of two is 64 => we need 6 bits
Subnet #2 needs 90 addresses so again, rounding up to 128 => we need 7 bits 
Subnet #3 only has 12 adresses, rounded gives us 16 => 4 bits.

You can fit this in one of two ways (you can permutate subnet 1 and three in more).

```
subnet 1 223.1.17.128/26 
subnet 2 223.1.17.0/25
subnet 3 223.1.17.192/28
```

or

```
subnet 1 223.1.17.0/26 
subnet 2 223.1.17.128/25
subnet 3 223.1.17.64/28
```

Comment: Thanks!
But why is it that a/25 network should start at either 0 or 128?

Comment: a/25 means you have remaining 7 bits. So we can divide that 256 addresses to 2 parts 0 to 127 and 128 to 255